# The requested URL / was not found on this server. (Django)

Tags: django

While deploying my Django project using apache2 following this tutorial: https://pythonprogramming.net/deploying-to-server-django-tutorial/ I am getting `Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.`

**/var/www/portfolio/portfolio/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from main.views import blog_detail, project_detail

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**/var/www/portfolio/main/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "main"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage_view, name="homepage_view"),
    path("contact/", views.contact_view, name="contact_view"),
    path("services/", views.services_view, name="services_view"),
    path("blog/", views.blog_view, name="blog_view"),
    path("blog/<str:slug>/", views.blog_detail, name="blog_detail"),
    path("projects/", views.projects_view, name="projects_view"),
    path("projects/<str:slug>/", views.project_detail, name="project_detail"),
]
```

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/portfolio.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myhostname

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/portfolio-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/portfolio-access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess portfolio processes=2 threads=25 python-path=/var/www/portfolio
    WSGIProcessGroup portfolio
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/portfolio/portfolio/wsgi.py

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/portfolio/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/portfolio/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /var/www/portfolio/static/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/portfolio/media/

    <Directory /var/www/portfolio/portfolio>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/portfolio/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/portfolio/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried going to /admin and it still 404s

Comment: What paths are in `'main.urls'`?

Comment: I'll add them to my post